# Can't install Windows 7 SDK

Tags: windows-7, sdk

I'm interesting in Windows Performance Analysis application. I've downloaded Windows 7 SDK which contains it.

After I run the setup the following message appears (for both winsdk_web.exe and DVD ISO's setup.exe): "Another running instance of this application was detected. Only one instance of this application may be running at any time."

There is no other setup.exe or msiexec running on my system  (Windows 7 Enterprise x64).

Did anyone get such issue? How can I install it?

UPDATE: I don't have serious problems with installing Win7 SDK on Windows 7 Enterprise x32.

Comment: Are you sure its not already installed?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I have Win SDK installed with VS2010 which is not Win 7 SDK, I guess. Anyway I don't have WPA installed, so I need to run the setup somehow to install it. VS2010 didn't provide me a choice, looks like it doesn't have WPA inside.

Answer (score 1):

Run it in "compatibility mode" for Windows Vista (by right click to change properties of the program)