# Cannot install Windows SDK

Tags: windows-7, installation

I'm struggling to install the Windows SDK  onto my W7 64bit machine.

I've read [Can't install Windows 7 SDK](https://superuser.com/questions/423315/cant-install-windows-7-sdk) but that has a different error to mine.

I can only find the option to download SDK for W7 and .NET 4 (although I already have 4.5 installed). So, I run the installer and shows it will be installed to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1`

After a few minutes, it fails with the following

> A problem occurred while installing selected Windows SDK components.
>
> Installation of the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7" product has reported the following error: Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information.

So, I do what it says, and try to navigate to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm`  but this does not exist. In fact, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1 doesn't exist. I have a folder called v8.0 though.

So, my question is, does the above suggest I should be installing the SDK for Windows 8 (despite being on W7 Ultimate)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the logs file. You may need to do a Control F (find) for the word `fail`.

In this case, it showed

> 07:20:40 24 September 2014: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Setup\SFX\vcredist_x64.exe installation failed with return code 5100

A quick Google search brings me to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2717426

And the main bits from the site are:

> This issue occurs when you install the Windows 7 SDK on a computer that has a newer version of the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable installed.  The Windows 7 SDK installs version 10.0.30319 of the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable.
>
> To resolve this issue, you must uninstall all versions of the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable before installing the Windows 7 SDK.  You may have one or more of the following products installed: